# Page Twitter's REST API with Node

Tags: node.js, rest, twitter

I am attempting to get a list of tweets from Twitter with a specific hashtag using Node js. Twitter has is it so that you can only get a maximum of 15 tweets for every request, so I need to make multiple requests if I want a sizable list of tweets. To let Twitter know that you want the next list of tweets, you need to provide a "max_id" variable, which should hold the minumum id of the list of tweets that you got back from the previous request. This process is documented [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines).

Here is my attempt at doing this:

```
var hashtag = "thisisahashtag"; // hashtag that we are looking for
var max_id = '';

do {
    twitter.search({
        q: "#" + hashtag,
        result_type: "recent",
        max_id: max_id
    },
        session.accessToken,
        session.accessTokenSecret,
        function(error, data, response) { // callback
            // get the ids of all the tweets from one response and do comparison for smallest one
            for(var i = 0; i < data.statuses.length; i++) {
                var id = data.statuses[i].id;
                if(max_id == '' || id < parseInt(max_id)) {
                    max_id = id;
                }
            }
            // do something with the data...
        }
    )
} while(max_id != '0');
```

I am using the node-twitter-api module to make the requests. This won't work because the outer loop will keep firing off without waiting for the query. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter lets you request up to 100 tweets at a time. I added a `count` parameter for this. You should initiate subsequent requests from your callback. That way you will serialize your requests.

```
function twitterSearch() {
    twitter.search({
        q: "#" + hashtag,
        result_type: "recent",
        max_id: max_id,
        count: 100 // MAX RETURNED ITEMS IS 100
    },
        session.accessToken,
        session.accessTokenSecret,
        function(error, data, response) { 
            for(var i = 0; i < data.statuses.length; i++) {
                var id = data.statuses[i].id;
                if(max_id == '' || id < parseInt(max_id)) {
                    max_id = id;
                }
            }

            // GET MORE TWEETS
            if (max_id != '0') 
                twitterSearch();
        }
    );
}
```